# Can we add flowchart in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I would like to add flowchart in Eclispe RCP.
So I wanted to know is there any free plugin for this purpose? If yes, can anyone please send the link.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an graphical editor the best choice is using [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). A basic tutorial is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-EMF/gef-emf.html). If you just want to present a flowchart you can use any available chart library for Java and integrate it into your Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: Thank you Frank.Can you please tell me few chart libraries for Java or even the resource will be helpful?